# Rewring the connection for lucee

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have this code working for coldfusion, but when i port it to lucee it fails, i know that macromedia does not work in lucee, how can i make this a possibility in lucee and want to remove the connection string, but the result should be exactly like the how the function is returning me

```
// open a connection to the database
            Class = createObject("java", "java.lang.Class");
            Class.forName("macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
            manager = createObject("java", "java.sql.DriverManager");
            connectionURL = "jdbc:macromedia:sqlserver://"& SESSION.USER.dbServer &":"& SESSION.USER.dbPortNumber & ";EncryptionMethod=SSL;ValidateServerCertificate=false;";
            connection = manager.getConnection(connectionURL, SESSION.USER.dbUser, SESSION.USER.dbPass);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i had the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might define this data source in the Admin instead of in the application code. One thing that screams "big red flag" in your existing code is that the database server name is defined in a cookie. Makes me wonder what other things are in cookie values that need to be refactored.

Read the documentation for [defining a data source](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/cookbooks/datasource-define-datasource.html):

```
this.datasources["myds"] = {
    class: 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver'
    , connectionString: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=true'
    , username: 'root'
    , password: "encrypted:5120611ea34c6123fd85120a0c27ab23fd81ea34cb854"
};
```

The example is for MySQL, but you need to find the correct driver name for SQL Server used by Lucee. Go to the admin and create the DSN there to find the driver name.

Comment: planning to get rid of this completely and want to rewrite this gist completely using modern technique , its a function and want to rewrite, if you can help, that will be great